# Airmon-ng differences

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, kali-linux, virtualbox, aircrack-ng

When I run airmon-ng on Ubuntu 20.04 terminal it gives me the details for PHY, Interface, Driver and Chipset of my laptop but when using Kali Linux on Virtual box it doesn't give me the details. What could be the problem? Both are updated and upgraded to their respective latest versions.

Comment: Could you include the output you are getting when you run the command in your question?

Comment: To put it simply, network devices work differently inside of virtual machines.

Comment: @Questionmark   I'm not running Ubuntu in a virtual machine. I'm running it as OS installed on HDD. Kali is the one in the virtual machine.

Comment: Your Ubuntu has direct access to the interface, because it's running on hardware. All your Kali VM is seeing is the virtual NIC provided by Virtual box.

Comment: @TsarGatxy, that is why Kali is the one that you are having trouble with.  It does not have direct access to the hardware.  It has to go though the virtualization layer.  I'd guess it is detecting your WiFi adapter as a wired ethernet port on the VM side.

Comment: @Questionmark  So what can I do to solve it? I don't think I can install Kali on the HDD and run 3 OS's on my laptop. Can it handle it?

Comment: @Questionmark  So what can I do to solve it? I don't think I can install Kali on the HDD and run 3 OS's on my laptop. Can it handle it?

Comment: Why shouldn't your laptop be able to run 3 OS-s? Not at the same time of course, but tripple-boot is not that uncommon. I frequently boot Kali from an external USB stick; maybe that is an option for you too?

Comment: @LjmDullaart   Yes. It's the way I'll do it.